# Using arrow keys to navigate in a table

Tags: javascript

UPDATE

I see that the code works in FF but not chrome, so the code itself works. Could it be to this part in the body?:

```
<body onkeypress="return onKeyPress(event)" onload="javascript:initBoard('Container'); makeBoard()">
```

What should I change to let Chrome pick up the key events too?

END UPDATE

---

I have a table I want to navigate in it using the arrow keys. Problem is, it aint working. My javascript code:

```
function setSel(x, y) {
    // Wrap around off the edges of the board
    if (x > 8) x = 0;
    if (x < 0) x = 8;
    if (y > 8) y = 0;
    if (y < 0) y = 8;

    var e = document.getElementById("Cell" + x + y);
    if (!e)
        return;
    if (sel)
        delClass(sel, "Selected");
    sel = e;
    addClass(sel, "Selected");
}

function onKeyPress(e) {
    if (sel == null)
        return;

    var keynum;
    var keychar;
    var numcheck;

    var e = window.event || e
    keynum = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.which : e.keyCode;

    switch(keynum) {
    case 37: // left arrow
        setSel(sel.x - 1, sel.y);
        return false;
    case 38: // up arrow
        setSel(sel.x, sel.y - 1);
        return false;
    case 39: // right arrow
        setSel(sel.x + 1, sel.y);
        return false;
    case 40: // down arrow
        setSel(sel.x, sel.y + 1);
        return false;
    case 46: // backspace/delete/space
    case 32:
    case 8: 
        board.setValue(sel.x, sel.y, 0);
        board.render();
        return false;
    default:
        keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
        if ((/\d/).test(keychar)) {
            var i = parseInt(keychar);
            if (i >= 0 && i <= 9) {
                board.setValue(sel.x, sel.y, parseInt(keychar));                
                board.render();
                return false;           
            }
        }
    }

    board.render();
    return true;
}
```

I've found this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BdVB9/ which does exactly what I need, but I am unsuccessful replicating it with my own code. So what am I missing?

Comment: Can you make your own Fiddle?

Comment: Please elaborate. What does "it ain't working" mean exactly? What does work and what doesn't? Have you already done any debugging and what results have you gotten from that?

Comment: It's almost impossible to debug something like this without seeing all the code.  What do addClass() and delClass() do?  board.setValue()?  board.render()?  You'd get much better assistance if you put up your own Fiddle.

Comment: The arrow keys do not work. I press them, but nothing happens (I do not "move" to the next cell if I press the right arrow key for example). I'll try to make my own fiddle, but the code is kinda big and strangled so I thought to try it this way first.

Comment: Updated the request see the update part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some more research and it seems that arrow keys are not supported in Chromium:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2606
and
http://help.dottoro.com/ljlwfxum.php